# Can't get the security rules to cascade to sub collections+allow create not working

Tags: android, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I have the following problems with my security rules:

I have the collection classrooms and inside there are classroom documents.
First when i check `if classroo.owner == request.auth.uid` it always returns false to allow create/update/delete, but when I do it with `if request.auth.uid in classroomData().userList` it works great to allow reading.

I tried using those security rules also note the ones that are commented out-

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    function isSignedIn() {
      return request.auth != null;
    }
    match /classrooms/{classroom} {
        allow read: if request.auth.uid in classroomData().userList;
        allow update, delete,create: if classroomData().owner == request.auth.uid;

        function classroomData() {
            return get(/databases/$(database)/documents/classrooms/$(classroom)).data
        }



        // match /classrooms/{classroom}/tasks/{taskId} {
        //     allow read: if request.auth.uid in classroomData().userList;
        //     allow update, delete,create: if parentDoc().owner == request.auth.uid;
        //  }
    }
  }
}
```

and the collections-

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bjh9W.png

Some classrooms have a sub collection of tasks with task related documents and I want users to not be able to read the tasks/classroom if they are not part of the parent `classroom.userList` and can't delete/write/update if they are not the owner.
Now my problem is I can't get my security rules to work...

Comment: Please edit your question to show the code for the rules and the client code that doesn't work the way you expect.  Don't just link to them - they should be in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you have in the owner field of a classroom document looks like an email address, not a Firebase Authentication UID.  That's not ever going to compare to `request.auth.uid`.  It looks like the document does have a UID in the uid field.  You should probably be using that for your security rules, not an email address.

```
allow update, delete, create: if classroomData().uid == request.auth.uid;
```

But since you're comparing the UID to the current document being matched by security rules, you don't need to get() that document.  You can access the properties of the current document being written using `resource`:

```
allow update, delete, create: if resource.data.uid == request.auth.uid;
```

You can simplify even further.  Since `write` access is the same as the combination of `update`, `delete`, and `create`, you can write the rule like this:

```
allow write: if resource.data.uid == request.auth.uid;
```